# Executing script on opening a msg in iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, scripting

I want to perform the following actions.

1. The msg is sent from my app to other iPhone.
2. The recipient opens that msg.
3. I want to execute some scripts (like some kind of animation or something) as soon as the msg is opened in iPhone.

So is this kind of action available in iPhone? Can O execute some kind of script like Perl or Python or something?

Comment: This is rather too broad for the Stack Overflow platform, I will cast a close vote.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can't run PERL or PYTHON on an iPhone (unless you jailbreak it).

What kind of message are you talking about? If they are plain TCP/IP messages, you can do a Cocoa Animation...